# Why am I allowed pickle instancemethods that are Theano functions, but not normal instancemethods?

Tags: python, oop, numpy, pickle, theano

In the process of using joblib to parallelize some model-fitting code involving Theano functions, I've stumbled across some behavior that seems odd to me.

Consider this very simplified example:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import theano
from theano import tensor as te
import numpy as np

class TheanoModel(object):
    def __init__(self):
        X = te.dvector('X')
        Y = (X ** te.log(X ** 2)).sum()
        self.theano_get_Y = theano.function([X], Y)

    def get_Y(self, x):
        return self.theano_get_Y(x)

def run(niter=100):
    x = np.random.randn(1000)
    model = TheanoModel()
    pool = Parallel(n_jobs=-1, verbose=1, pre_dispatch='all')

    # this fails with `TypeError: can't pickle instancemethod objects`...
    results = pool(delayed(model.get_Y)(x) for _ in xrange(niter))

    # # ... but this works! Why?
    # results = pool(delayed(model.theano_get_Y)(x) for _ in xrange(niter))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

I understand why the first case fails, since `.get_Y()` is clearly an instancemethod of `TheanoModel`. What I don't understand is why the second case *works*, since `X`, `Y` and`theano_get_Y()` are only declared within the `__init__()` method of `TheanoModel`. `theano_get_Y()` can't be evaluated until the `TheanoModel` instance has been created. Surely, then, it should also be considered an instancemethod, and should therefore be unpickleable? In fact, even still works if I explicitly declare `X` and `Y` to be attributes of the `TheanoModel` instance.

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

---

### Update

Just to illustrate why I think this behaviour is particularly weird, here are a few examples of some other callable member objects that don't take `self` as the first argument:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import theano
from theano import tensor as te
import numpy as np

class TheanoModel(object):
    def __init__(self):
        X = te.dvector('X')
        Y = (X ** te.log(X ** 2)).sum()
        self.theano_get_Y = theano.function([X], Y)
        def square(x):
            return x ** 2
        self.member_function = square
        self.static_method = staticmethod(square)
        self.lambda_function = lambda x: x ** 2

def run(niter=100):
    x = np.random.randn(1000)
    model = TheanoModel()
    pool = Parallel(n_jobs=-1, verbose=1, pre_dispatch='all')

    # # not allowed: `TypeError: can't pickle function objects`
    # results = pool(delayed(model.member_function)(x) for _ in xrange(niter))

    # # not allowed: `TypeError: can't pickle function objects`
    # results = pool(delayed(model.lambda_function)(x) for _ in xrange(niter))

    # # also not allowed: `TypeError: can't pickle staticmethod objects`
    # results = pool(delayed(model.static_method)(x) for _ in xrange(niter))

    # but this is totally fine!?
    results = pool(delayed(model.theano_get_Y)(x) for _ in xrange(niter))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

None of them are pickleable with the exception of the `theano.function`!

Comment: Nice find -- I don't think your `theano_get_Y` is instance method enough as in `<bound method ... etc>` to be caught by that test. Also the call to `theano.function` makes theano compile the expressions you define, essentially making the result totally independent of all the other variables defined in the scope of `__init__`. Thus I think it should be seen just as an unbound callable object. (I am handwaving a little, because I am not even 41.9% sure of how this *exactly* works internally)

Comment: @eickenberg Interesting - I get why `theano_get_Y` doesn't need to refer to `X` and `Y` after it has been created, but it still refers to/is referred to by the `<TheanoModel>` instance. It seems particularly odd in the context of all the other similar types of callable object that can't be pickled.

Comment: Maybe you could add a test using a callable class instance as described in @Winsto Ewert's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theano functions aren't python functions. Instead they are python objects that override `__call__`.  This means that you can call them just like a function but internally they are really objects of some custom class. In consequence, you can pickle them.

Comment: and those don't have a chance of referring to a weird local scope like  dynamic definitions and lambdas do. Thanks!